WindRoseAxe generated incompleted axis
I just encounter this problem, which never happened before.
The axis is not complete. The code works well in previous runs.
I am not sure what detail I should provide for resolving the problem. Please let me know.
Python version : 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
matplotlib version 3.7.5
Data in *csv format for testing can be downloaded va: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nIIT0vTVOtj2B89Fxh1tzBLqsYQq_hXP/view?usp=drive_link

My code is :
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_path = 'the directory with csv file' 
# the code will process all the *csv files in the directory

has_legend = False
files = os.listdir(file_path)

def create_rose(file_name):
    # Create wind speed and direction variables
    # CSV data structure : Date , Time , Speed , Direction
    csv = np.genfromtxt(file_path + file_name, 
                    delimiter =',', skip_header =1)
    pdf_1 = file_path + 'with_legend_'+ file_name + '.pdf'
    pdf_2 = file_path + 'no_legend_'+ file_name + '.pdf'
    
    
    # ws: wind speed
    # wd: wind direction
    # in python, range index starts with zero
    # ws = csv[ : , 2]
    
    ws = csv[ : , 0]
    wd = csv[ : , 1] + 15
    speed_bin = np.arange(0, 4, 0.5)
    
    
    len(ws)
    
    ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
    ax.bar(wd, ws, normed =True, opening=1, edgecolor='white', bins = speed_bin, cmap = cm.jet, nsector = 12) 
    ax.set_xticklabels([90, 45, 0, 315, 270, 225, 180, 135])
          
    if(has_legend):
        ax.set_legend()
        ax.legend(loc ='lower right', decimal_places=2)
        plt.savefig(pdf_1)
    else:
        plt.savefig(pdf_2)
            
for file_x in files:
    print(file_x)
    create_rose(file_x)

print('All is finished')


Add your dataset as well in order to have a [mcve]

@jlandercy, the download link is provided, you may have a look. Thank you.

The file is not available, access denied.

It is resolved by updating conda from version 4 to version 24.
As a python package user, I have no idea. Grateful with anyone who can explain.
Thanks.
